# OpenLiberty ignoring WEB-INF/ibm-application-bnd.xml

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

My application (my-app.war) has a JAX-RS endpoint, secured with a given role, like this:

Endpoint.java

```
@Path("endpoint/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@DeclareRoles({"ADMIN_ROLE"})
public class Endpoint {
  @POST
  @RolesAllowed({"ADMIN_ROLE"})
  public void post() {
  }
}
```

server.xml

```
<server>
  <featureManager>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.1</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-3.0</feature>
  </featureManager>

  <application id="my-app" context-root="/" location="my-app.war" type="war">
  </application>

  <variable name="default.http.port" defaultValue="9080"/>
  <variable name="default.https.port" defaultValue="9443"/>

  <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" httpPort="${default.http.port}" httpsPort="${default.https.port}"/>

  <basicRegistry realm="defaultRealm">
    <user name="test-user" password="test-password"/>
    <group name="ADMIN_GROUP">
      <member name="test-user"/>
    </group>
  </basicRegistry>

</server>
```

Now I have to bind `ADMIN_GROUP` to `ADMIN_ROLE`.

If I do it on **server.xml** `application`, then everything works fine:

```
  <application id="my-app" context-root="/" location="my-app.war" type="war">
    <application-bnd>
      <security-role name="ADMIN_ROLE">
        <group name="ADMIN_GROUP" />
      </security-role>
    </application-bnd>
  </application>
```

The application is deployed and upon invoking the endpoint without authentication, it returns 403 (authentication required). When supplied with authentication header, it returns 204 (no content) as intended.

**Now the problem lies when I try to configure the binding in `ibm-application-bnd.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<application-bnd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-application-bnd_1_2.xsd"
  xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  version="1.2">
<
  <security-role name="ADMIN_ROLE">
    <group name="ADMIN_GROUP" />
  </security-role>
</application-bnd>
```

I've put it both in `META-INF/ibm-application-bnd.xml` and `WEB-INF/ibm-application-bnd.xml`. But both of them are completely ignored (I've even went as far as adding invalid xml there, but get no error message from OpenLiberty).

Every call to the endpoint returns 403, even when supplied with authentication.

In https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=liberty-configuring-authorization-applications-in, it says [emphasis added]:

> Configure the authorization information such as the user and group to role mapping.
> You can configure the authorization table in the following ways:
>
> - If you have an EAR file, you can add the authorization configuration definition to the ibm-application-bnd.xml or ibm-application-bnd.xmi file.
> - If you have standalone WAR files, **you can add the authorization table definitions to the server.xml** file under the respective application element. You can use the WebSphere® Application Server Developer Tools for Eclipse to do this.

Does this mean that for **war applications** the binding **MUST BE** on server.xml?

Comment: I've just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524920/group-to-role-mapping-in-ibm-liberty-wlp-when-using-war.

Comment: Then I've found https://stackoverflow.com/a/43551289/1535706

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32060329/1535706), `META-INF/ibm-application-bnd.xml` - though undocumented - can be used inside a web archive.

Then I've `mvn package` my project, and inpected it's war file (showing only relevant files):

```
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2021-04-28 22:13   META-INF/
      131  2021-04-28 22:13   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        0  2021-04-28 22:13   WEB-INF/
        0  2021-04-28 22:13   WEB-INF/classes/
        0  2021-04-28 22:13   WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/
        0  2021-04-28 22:13   WEB-INF/lib/
        0  2021-04-22 17:58   WEB-INF/beans.xml
      134  2021-04-28 22:13   WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/ibm-application-bnd.xml
      592  2021-04-28 22:13   WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml
   300365  2021-04-15 09:58   WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.14.1.jar
  1745700  2021-04-15 09:59   WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.14.1.jar
      393  2021-04-28 21:50   WEB-INF/web.xml
        0  2021-04-28 22:13   META-INF/maven/
---------                     -------
```

Now note that there are `META-INF/*` entries and `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/*` entries.

Then I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43551289/1535706) (which is unrelated to liberty/openliberty). It's first sentence struck me in awe:

> It looks like your META-INF folder is in src/main/resources directory.

Exactly like mine. So I moved `META-INF` from `src/main/resources` to `src/main/webapp`.

Now the war lists as:

```
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2021-04-28 22:22   META-INF/
      131  2021-04-28 22:22   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        0  2021-04-28 22:22   WEB-INF/
        0  2021-04-28 22:22   WEB-INF/classes/
        0  2021-04-28 22:22   WEB-INF/lib/
      134  2021-04-28 22:13   META-INF/ibm-application-bnd.xml
      592  2021-04-27 10:19   META-INF/persistence.xml
        0  2021-04-22 17:58   WEB-INF/beans.xml
   300365  2021-04-15 09:58   WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.14.1.jar
  1745700  2021-04-15 09:59   WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.14.1.jar
      393  2021-04-28 21:50   WEB-INF/web.xml
        0  2021-04-28 22:22   META-INF/maven/
---------                     -------
```

Now the file `ibm-application-bnd.xml` gets processed. **And it works. EXCEPT THAT...**

This way JPA is not working anymore.

It seems that `META-INF/persistence.xml` must be in `src/main/resources` after all.

**Now I have two `META-INF/` folders (¯\_(ツ)_/¯).**

---

**UPDATE**

Apart from having two `META-INF/` folders (a problem on its own), now my tests can't access resources from `META-INF/` (the other one, in `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF` is readily available, as every resource inside `WEB-INF/classes/`).

Then why would I need to access `ibm-application-bnd.xml` from tests, you might ask. Because I'm using arquillian, and I need to create a deployment, and I need to include these role <-> group mappings.

Now I have 3 options:

1. create a copy of `ibm-application-bnd.xml` inside `src/test/resources`; the problem here is that I need to keep both in sync;
2. add `src/main/webapps` to the surefire/failsafe classpath (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59773282/1535706));
3. specifically for Liberty/OpenLiberty, I can rely on an implicit mapping (assuming each group bind to a role with the same name; go look for CWWKS2104I [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/zos?topic=messages-cwwks)). This is the one I'm choosing for the moment.

Options 1 and 3 share the same downside: the tested code is not EXACTLY the code that will be deployed to production.

Option 2 has another downside: when running tests through the IDE, this extra folder must also be added to the classpath (unless the IDE has a very good integration with maven and can read surefire/failsafe configuration).

The

Comment: Since the packaging question is different from the original question I won't add an answer, but here's another way you could package your resources:   https://gist.github.com/scottkurz/6a21755728e5543764b8700ad98e5858   Feel free to reach out the the Open Liberty dev team at:   https://gitter.im/OpenLiberty/developer-experience

Comment: Interesting. I'll consider that. If my IDE (vscode) understands that configuration, I'll go with it.